# How to continue to train SVM based on the previous model

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

We all know that the objective function of SVM is iteratively trained. In order to continue training, at least we can store all the variables used in the iterations if we want to continue on the same training dataset.

While, if we want to train on a slightly different dataset, what should we do to make full use of the previously trained model? Or does this kind of thought make sense? I think it is quite reasonable if we train a K-means model. But I am not sure if it still makes sense for the SVM problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this doesn't make sense. SVM training is an [optimization process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Primal_form) with regard to every training set vector. Each training vector has an associated coefficient, which as a result is either `0` (irrelevant) or `> 0` (support vector). Adding another training vector imposes another, different, optimization problem.

The only way to reuse information from previous training I can think of is to choose support vectors from the previous training and add them to the new training set. I'm not sure, but this probably will negatively affect generalization - [VC dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension) of an SVM is related to the number of support vectors, so adding previous support vectors to the new dataset is likely to increase the support vector count.

Apparently, there are more possibilities, as noted in [lennon310's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21189243/2642204).

Comment: yes, I think the number of SV will probably increase. I asked this question because I did not understand hard negative mining procedure. It will remove some *easy* negative training examples and add some *hard* training examples. But I do not know whether it is an incremental training process or we just change the negative examples and re-train the SVM from scratch.

Comment: yes, I just explained why I felt puzzled about this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are some literature on this topic:

1. [alpha-seeding](http://trs-new.jpl.nasa.gov/dspace/bitstream/2014/15583/1/00-1286.pdf), in which the training data is divided into chunks. After you train a SVM on the `ith` chunk, you take those and use them to train your SVM with the `(i+1)th` chunk.
2. [Incremental SVM](http://www.isn.ucsd.edu/svm/incremental/) serves as an online learning in which you update a classifier with new examples rather than retrain the entire data set.
3. [SVM heavy](http://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/shiltona/svm/) package with online SVM training as well.

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing is what an online learning algorithm does and unfortunately the classic definition for SVM is done in a batch fashion.

However, there are several solvers for SVM that produces quasy optimal hypothesis to the underneath optimization problem in an online learning way. In particular my favourite is Pegasos-SVM which can find a good near optimal solution in linear time:

http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~nati/Publications/PegasosMPB.pdf

Comment: Thanks. Pegasos-SVM seems a very powerful online learning tool! Anybody interested in Pegasos-SVM may want to try the [Sofia-ml](https://code.google.com/p/sofia-ml/). @Pedrom